# How do you convert a system of symbolic sympy ODEs to matrix form?

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to (ultimately) simulate an inverted pendulum having a PID controller.
I am employing the Euler-Lagrange method to derive the equations of motion using SymPy.
I can compute the Euler-Lagrange equations in SymPy just fine.
Now that I have my symbolic differential equations, I would like to write them in matrix form.
It can be done by hand, but I would like to know if SymPy can separate the 2nd time-derivates out, put them in a vector, and put the rest into a matrix.
Here is the code I have so far:

```
#Import Libraries
import math
import numpy as np
import vpython as vp
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
from numpy import *
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Allow display of symbols
sp.init_printing()

#Set up symbolic equations

####Symbolic Variables####
m1, m2 = sp.symbols('m1 m2') #masses of rad & cart
l = sp.symbols('l') #Length of rod
J = sp.symbols('J') #Rotational moment of inertia
t, g, F, b = sp.symbols('t g F b') #Gravitational acceleration, time, forces
z, theta1 = sp.symbols('z, theta1', cls = sp.Function)
x, y =sp.symbols('x y')

#Rotational Inertia
J = (m1*(l/2)**2)/12

####Time Derivatives####
theta1 = theta1(t)
z = z(t) 
z_d = sp.diff(z, t)
theta1_d = sp.diff(theta1, t)
z_dd = sp.diff(z_d, t)
theta1_dd = sp.diff(theta1_d, t)

####Coordinates of component centers of mass####
x1 = l/2*sp.sin(theta1) + z
y1 = l/2*sp.cos(theta1)
x2 = z
y2 = 0
v1_sq = sp.diff(x1,t)**2 + sp.diff(y1,t)**2
v1 = sp.sqrt(v1_sq)
v2 = sp.diff(x2,t)

#Kinetic Energy
K1 = (1/2)*m1*(v1**2) + (1/2)*J*(sp.diff(theta1,t)**2)
K2 = (1/2)*m2*(sp.diff(z,t)**2)
K = K1 + K2

#Potential Energy
P = m1*g*l/2*sp.cos(theta1)

#Lagrangian
L = K - P

#Compute the Euler Lagrange Equation

#Compute dL/dq
dL_dz = sp.diff(L, z).simplify()
dL_dtheta1 = sp.diff(L, theta1).simplify()

#Compute dL/dq_dt
dL_dz_dt = sp.diff(L, z_d).simplify()
dL_dtheta1_dt = sp.diff(L, theta1_d).simplify()

#Compute d/dt(dL/dq_dt)
d_dt_dL_dz_dt = sp.diff(dL_dz_dt, t).simplify()
d_dt_dL_dtheta1_dt = sp.diff(dL_dtheta1_dt, t).simplify()

#Compute d/dt(dL/dq_dt) - dL/dq
LE1 = d_dt_dL_dz_dt.simplify() - dL_dz.simplify()
LE2 = d_dt_dL_dtheta1_dt.simplify() - dL_dtheta1.simplify()
LE = LE1 + LE2
```

I have tried using sympy.linear_eq_to_matrix(equations, *symbols), but the 'symbols' portion is a differentiated variable in my case, causing SymPy to issue this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-eab6a82bce2c> in <module>
     88 
     89 b = sp.linsolve([LE1, LE2], (z_dd, theta1_dd))
---> 90 sp.linear_eq_to_matrix([LE1, LE2], *[z_dd, theta1_dd])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solveset.py in linear_eq_to_matrix(equations, *symbols)
   2555     for i in symbols:
   2556         if not isinstance(i, Symbol):
-> 2557             raise ValueError(filldedent('''
   2558             Expecting a Symbol but got %s
   2559             ''' % i))

ValueError: 
Expecting a Symbol but got Derivative(theta1(t), (t, 2))
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Your equations are nonlinear so can't be written in matrix form without linearisation. Rather than computing the Euler-Lagrange equations you can derive equations for the equilibria and mass and stiffness matrices for the linearised form directly from the Lagrangian.

Comment: Oscar, thanks for your reply.  I didn't realize you had responded so quickly. I am new to Stack Overflow, and still learning the interface. As for my project, I just broke down and created my matrices by hand, complete with linearization. The real question was: how do I get python to convert a set of equations into matrix form?